# pam_tally is not supporting user locking after failed attempts on CentOS

Tags: linux, centos, authentication, centos5, pam

After adding the below configurations in /etc/pam.d/system-auth.
The user account is not getting locked after multiple failed attempts. As per the below configuration the account should be locked after 3 failed attempts and the account should be locked for 1200 seconds as specified by unlock_time. Also, after adding the below configuration the failedlog started writing for the users failed attempts. Kindly let me know if there is any mistake in the below configuration so that I can lock the user account after 3 failed attempts. The OS I am using CentOS5.3.

```
              auth        required      pam_tally2.so deny=3 unlock_time=1200 magic_root
              account     required      pam_tally2.so
```

Full file content:

```
 auth        required      pam_env.so
 auth        sufficient    pam_unix.so nullok try_first_pass
 auth        requisite     pam_succeed_if.so uid >= 500 quiet
 auth        required      pam_deny.so
 auth        required      pam_tally.so magic_root
 account     required      pam_tally.so deny=3 magic_root lock_time=180
 account     required      pam_unix.so
 account     sufficient    pam_succeed_if.so uid < 500 quiet
 account     required      pam_permit.so
 password    required      pam_cracklib.so try_first_pass retry=3 minlen=14,dcredit=-1,ucredit=-1,ocredit=-1 lcredit=-1
 password    sufficient    pam_unix.so md5 remember=12 use_authtok
 password    required      pam_deny.so
 session     optional      pam_keyinit.so revoke
 session     required      pam_limits.so
 session     [success=1 default=ignore] pam_succeed_if.so service in crond quiet use_uid
 session     required      pam_unix.so
```

Comment: The order of the directives is important, please add the full file to your question.

Comment: I have added the full file contents.